# how to get this button in layout of an android file

Tags: android, uiview

Can anyone say what is the button in the image refers to and how to design this in a xml file

[image]

in a checked textview layout how to get the check box at the right corner normally it is showing in the left end

is it an image, please tell me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Siva K here is sample Code for using [Preferences](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/)...

Download the Code and check you code in folder `Prefs/Dialogs`

Answer (score 1):

This PrefeenceActivity in android . You can see it in setting of your device or emulator.
To use PreferenceACtivity in android follow this linkhttp://jetpad.org/2011/01/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/